# Как парсить мета-тег property?

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Функция `get_meta_tags` в php даёт возможность получить значение из мета-тега такого формата:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Содержимое тега">
```

А как при помощи мета-тега парсить содержимое мета-тега с таким форматом:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Содержимое мета-тега">
```

Comment: вот [так][1] например


  [1]:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454644/how-to-get-open-graph-protocol-of-a-webpage-by-php

Comment: На уровне функции это не решается? Только костылями?

Comment: @tiNtw, боюсь что да

Comment: Ещё нашёл вот что:
http://www.diffbot.com/